# Python simplecv toString() back to image

Tags: python, sockets, opencv, python-2.7, simplecv

I have problem when i send image converted to string (with simplecv method toString()) from server to socket, i cant convert it back to image.

**[EDIT]**
Added code as comment suggests

However i need to "stream" my screen as fast as possible to clients. Please correct me if i'm going to wrong direction.

I've tried following (client):

```
while 1:
    x = sock.recv(4096)
    y = sock.recv(4096)
    imgSize = (int(x),int(y))
    img = sock.recv(429467296)
    try:
        if img != None:
            bmp = cv.CreateImageHeader(imgSize, cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3)
            cv.SetData(bmp,img)
            cv.CvtColor(bmp,bmp, cv.CV_RGB2BGR)
            screenImg = Image(bmp)
            img = None
            screenImg.show()
   except:
       print 'Error with image'
```

host:

```
while 1:
    screenImg = sc.getImage()
    screenImg = screenImg.scale(0.5)
    string = screenImg.toString()
    client.sendall(str(screenImg.size()[0]))
    client.sendall(str(screenImg.size()[1]))
    client.sendall(string)
```

but i get Microsoft visual c++ runtime library error telling that pythonw.exe has terminated unusual way

Is it possible that this could be caused by the loss of data when transferring? Or is it that i use too large buffernumber when receiving data?

Comment: Maybe you could try and find more information about why your Python runtime is terminating? Try and catch an exception - or is it running out of memory?

Comment: Could you try posting a complete minimum-working-example of the code? Perhaps the problem might be with some unrelated part of the system, since the code snippit you posted looks fine to me.

Comment: Yes, it could be because i try to send too much data at once?

Answer (score 0):

The packet size maybe too large. I would create an extremely small image and verify it is set over with something like:

```
img = Image((5,5))
```

This will make a black image that is 5 x 5.  You could also do an img.invert() to see if it changes to completely white.  I would also set a break point in the .NET IDE at the sock.recv() and manually look at the socket buffer to verify that the strings match before trying to cast into an Image, or if you can't break point than cout >> to a file.

Comment: I did some testing and noticed that it couldn't send whole string at once, so i split it into big sections and it worked, but only when i broke the loop in server immediately after sending last chunk.